# Can you install multiple C++ compilers on Windows?

Tags: c++, mingw

I have Dev C++ but another tutorial I want to do says to install MinGW Code::Blocks. I just want to see what that one is like, I know I can simply use Dev C++. But, is it possible to just add both to the path and use whichever one I want?

Comment: You can have multiple installed at once, but probably only one in the `PATH` at once.

Comment: get visual c++ it is the best

Comment: At work I have 5 versions of Visual Studio installed along with at least 2 versions of gcc (one being mingw) on my windows 8 desktop.

Comment: @Bot Can´t you get even more opinionated? Such statements won´t lead to anything but a long long discussion.

Comment: but come on intellisense and it has dll and aslo win32 programming support. Not alot of other compilers have those qualities. Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks is for beginners going into c++.

Comment: @Bot You don´t even know what a compiler is. The compiler doesn´t have Intellisense etc.etc. And *every* Windows compiler can handle DLLs and the Win32 API. (Btw. If we define "quality" as something measurable and not opion-based like standard-compliance, VS is the worst out of the big 3. They don´t even want to achieve it properly.)

Comment: Visual C++ features tools for developing and debugging C++ code, especially code written for the Microsoft Windows API, the DirectX API, and the Microsoft .NET Framework. How do I NOT know what a compiler is when I use it everyday?

Comment: @Bot Nicely copied from ... somewhere. But that has nothing to do with the topic. edit: I really have doubts that you use the VS compiler manually at all.

Comment: yeah... It doesn't have anything to do with the topic. Oops. EDIT: I use compilers everyday not limited to the VS compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding in your question. DevC++ and Code::Blocks are IDEs, not compilers. You definitely can have more than one IDE installed at a time.

That said, the answer to your question as asked is yes, you can install multiple c++ compilers on Windows. But putting more than one in your path is likely to cause problems.

Comment: If you want to access the compiler(s) from the command line you can create a batch file for each that sets the environment, path etc. as the vcvars.bat does for MS Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I have installed two compilers: mingw first and TDM-GCC second, put both in PATH, and when I type "gcc --version" in the command prompt, it gives me the version about the one I've installed first (mingw). So you probably aren't going to have any problem with having multiple compilers in PATH, but only the first installed will be used, until you delete it from PATH.